# Line segment and Sphere intersect

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics

How can I check it if a line3D/ or ray is intersecting a sphere?

Answer (score 4):

The real time rendering web-site is good source for different intersection algorithms (including ray/sphere intersection):

http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: Except that a ton of the links are down these days.

Answer (score 4):

The problem logically reduces to finding the *shortest distance between the ray (line) and the sphere centre*. If that distance is shorter than the sphere radius, there is an intersection.

Of course, there's [a formula for line-point distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is a part of ray tracer design. Look at the ray and sphere intersection. It is very simple and commonly used in every ray tracer.

Comment: You could have added a link or something at least.